# How to update certain rows using UPDATE function using sqldf R package?

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, sql-update, sqldf

I have two tables: dat1 and dat2.

```
names(dat1):
id, filename, kd_estimated, kd_95CI_low, kd_95CI_upp, start_time, end_time, max_response, min_response   , RMSE, resp_95CI_low, resp_95CI_upp



  names(dat2) = names(dat1)
```

The data looks like the following:

```
1, A1_a1H12.xls.txt, 0.00172, 0.0017, 0.00174, 450, 600, 0.267, 0.204, 0.00256, 0.229, 0.229
```

I want to update dat1 with dat2 when the file names are the same. Below is my code:

```
mydata_up <- sqldf(c("UPDATE dat1 SET kd_estimated = dat2.kd_estimated FROM dat2 WHERE dat2.filename = dat1.filename", "SELECT * FROM dat1"))
```

However, I always get the following error:

"Error: near "FROM": syntax error"

No clue :-( Thank you for the help.

Comment: Hi Sophia, please select the code part and then click on "{}" this logo . this will convert code part in gray area so that everyone can understand which lines are code and which are text. Thanks

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: Another easy method: highlight the code and press `Ctrl-K`, same thing. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help provides help on how to format, and while it sounds petty, a well-formatted question makes differentiating text from code from data from text from ... much simpler, and formats code as fixed-width, which is perhaps how many (most? all? idk) IDEs present code-editing. Making it appealing to the eyes makes it just a little easier for people to take a slightly-longer look at it, potentially addressing your question(s).

Comment: @GMB, it's `sqldf`, which is an R package that uses the SQLite engine in the background. I typically think that [tag:sqldf] is sufficient, since there are SQLite things that do not apply as logically in the `sqldf` context.

Comment: Sophia, given you are using SQL syntax within R, it will be important to be clear with your nomenclature. R does not have "tables", so I'm going to assume `dat1` and `dat2` are data frames. Please provide a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and please show us your expected output. What do you mean by "update dat1 with dat2 when the file names are the same"? Do you mean doing the equivalent of `if (dat1[1,2] == dat2[1,2]) dat1 <- dat2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many databases, you could use a correlated subquery for this:

```
UPDATE dat1 SET kd_estimated = (
    SELECT dat2.kd_estimated 
    FROM dat2 
    WHERE dat2.filename = dat1.filename
)
```

If there may be missing matches in `dat2`, then:

```
UPDATE dat1 SET kd_estimated = (
    SELECT dat2.kd_estimated 
    FROM dat2 
    WHERE dat2.filename = dat1.filename
)
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dat2 
    WHERE dat2.filename = dat1.filename
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My question may be not clear. I want to update certain rows in dat1 with the rows in dat2, where the file name is the same, e.g., in dat1, a1, 7; a3, 8; and in dat2, a1, 9, a3, 10. I want to update a1 and a3 in dat1 with 9 and 10, respectively. Thank you.

Comment: @sophia: that’s what the query does. Please give it a try.

Comment: Thank you so much. The second part ("...missing matches") is exactly what I need. I only tried the first part before. Take care.

Comment: could you please help me to understand "WHERE EXISTS" mean? Thank you!